# Java "incompatable types" still not understood; What is wrong?

Tags: java, string, incompatibletypeerror

It seems that it is correct, I just need help to find out why it is giving me this error. Here is the prompt:

1.Create a MyStr class

2.Write a method in MyStr Class called break( ).
The method break( ) accepts a string as its parameter and returns the string with last two characters in the front.

Here is an example of the output:

1. MyStr.break(Hello) 
   returns loHel

   Mystr.break(Active) 
   returns veActi

Here is my code so far:

```
public class Main {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    MyStr.strBreak("Morse");
    MyStr.strBreak("School");
  }
}

public class MyStr{
  public static void strBreak(String word){
    int x = word.length() - 2;
    return(word.substring(x) + word.substring(0, x));
  }
}
```

Comment: What line of code indicates an error about `incompatible types`?

Comment: Your method is declared as not returning anything (void) but you are actually returning something (a string)

Comment: line 4 return incompatibility and if I remove void it does not work ?

Comment: You should not remove void. You should specify the correct return type. Your method returns a String. So the return type should be String, not void. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/methods.html

Comment: @JBNizet I see! tysm, this was very helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

change

```
public static void strBreak(String word){
```

to

```
public static String strBreak(String word){
```

because this method returns a string.

a keyword `void` means 'nothing' and it's used to declare a method that returns nothing. If a method returns anything, you should specify a correct data type in the method declaration.

Answer (score 0):

```
public class MyStr{ 
    public static String strBreak(String word){ 
        int x = word.length() - 2; 
        return(word.substring(x) + word.substring(0, x)); 
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The below will do.

```
    public class Main {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    String str=MyStr.strBreak("Morse");
    MyStr.strBreak("School");
    System.out.println(str);
  }
}

public class MyStr{
  public static String strBreak(String word){
    int x = word.length() - 2;
    return(word.substring(x) + word.substring(0, x));
  }
}
```

This prints out-

```
seMor
```

- Your Main class is not printing any result
- Your MyStr is returning void instead of String